# Booting error on GRUB after Backtrack installation

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I have installed windows a 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 already, I was trying to install backtrack but at the start of the installation, I turned the computer off because it told me it was going to boot automatically or something like this, then when I tried to open my computer again, I got this

```
error: unknown file system.
grub rescue>
```

Comment: Backtrack is old and unsupported, you should instead use Kali. Try to recover your GRUB with Ubuntu then install something actual.

Comment: The solution is this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/182863/6005

Answer (score 0):

Place ubuntu on a USB Live, boot from it and do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Do the recommended repair and then reboot.

Comment: NYTHING WILL BE DELETED?

Comment: and should i boot the ubuntu or can i just choose try ubuntu

Comment: Nothing is deleted. Just select "Try ubuntu" and after booting into the live usb, open terminal and to the above steps.